# What does this sentence mean: "It is not like those women would have looked at you twice before Christmas."

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, idiomatic-language

This is from famous British TV drama, the Eastenders, a man is saying to a woman:

**It is not like those women would have looked at you twice before Christmas.** [TV drama - Eastenders](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhnuI1QioGM) see: (0:44-0:48)

I didn't understand what it means. So I researched:

**"It is not like ....."** is used when you want to give a reason for wanting to do (or not to do) something.

**"...would have looked.."** seems like conditional **Type 3** (but there is no "if" or implied "if" in this sentence),

So, even if I force to combine the two sentences, nothing sensible comes up.

What is more, the second sentence is in the past and the first sentence is  in the present. Even this causes a confusion to to create a sensible meaning.

Really, what does it mean? what does the speaker means to say?

Comment: 'It's not like...' means' 'it is (significantly, in the speaker's opinion) not the case that...' - _Why won't you lend me your bicycle? **It's not like** you ever ride it_

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, Ok, I understand it, however it still does not make sense even if I replace "it is not like ..." with "it is not the case that ...": "It is not the case that those women would have looked at you twice before Christmas." What does it mean?

Comment: "to look at something twice" means to take a second glance or to give serious consideration to something. I can't actually see this in any idiom dictionaries but I'd expect it to be in somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is not like** in that usage is synonymous with **it is not as though**.

> It is not as though those women would have looked at you twice before Christmas.

I don't know the context and out of context I have no idea how Christmas figures into this sentence. So let's use some other examples instead.

> These shoes are too tight.
>
> -- Why don't you try putting on the left shoe first.
>
> Why on earth would you suggest that?  It's not as though it would make any difference.

Or

> Why on earth would you suggest that?  It's not like it would make any difference.

P.S. Here in a past-tense context:

> The shoes *were* too tight.
>
> -- *Didn't* you try putting on the left shoe first?
>
> Why on earth would you suggest that? It's not as though it **would have made** any difference.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I perfectly understood when I consider it functions as "it is not as though". This way the meaning sits very well. On the other hand, I see "would" being used in your example sentences and it makes sense, but then why "....would have looked at ....." is used instead of "....would look at...." in this sentence?

Comment: In the EastEnders episode, Christmas has already come and gone. It's in the past, hence **would have looked**. As the character says @0:57, "I came here to talk about the future, not rehash the past".   If Christmas is in the future, one could say "It's not as if those women **would look** at you twice before Christmas". Or even "**will look** at you twice."  I've added a P.S. to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> **It is not like those women would have looked at you twice before Christmas.**

Okay I don't watch EastEnders but from this I know something major happened to this person at Christmas, they won lots of money, lost lots of weight, something to make them romantically a better "catch".

This means before this big life changing event at Christmas those women would have looked at him once and thought to themselves "this person isn't attractive" and walked away. They "wouldn't have looked at him twice".

To steal Stuart F's brilliant description:

> "to look at something twice" means to take a second glance or to give serious consideration to something.

To break it down

> It is not like those women

this is something the women would have NOT done, so examples with less ambiguity in the second half.

> It's not like you can jump to the moon
> It's not like you can travel back in time to fix it.

This example has a structure similar to your question. So something (unnamed) has happened at Christmas so the start of the statement is in the past, the end of the sentence is in the present.

> It's not like he ever talked to you before Christmas, so what are you complaining about?

Comment: Thanks. It started to get clear. I understood the second sentence. How about the first part? Why is the first sentence in present tense then, whereas the situation is in the past. "Those women didn't use to look at her". So, shouldn't he have said "It WAS NOT like .........." instead of "It ISN'T like ......"?

Comment: all I can say is because before Christmas is in the past as we are now in March. "Would have"  is a version of past tense, I don't know which version.

Comment: I have added hopefully more explanation in the answer. If you need an in depth discussion of tenses you will have to ask a new question highlighting you are interested in tenses and not meaning. Or edit this one to highlight that.

Comment: EastEnders is _amazingly_ bad. I say that as a Briton from London.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey it used to be just bad when it started, but now it is comically bad

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation, not knowing anything about the context, is that since Christmas is a holiday (a *holy* day), when the birth of the Christian son of God is celebrated, women won't be looking at men in a 'secular' (sexual) way around that time, whereas before they might have.

Looking twice at someone implies an interest, also often a romantic one. You see someone once, possibly quickly, process it, and realize you want to see it again.

If this is the correct interpretation, then **what the speaker is saying is that the person they are addressing is even less attractive to women now**:

> "It's not like those women would have been interested in you *before* Christmas", *let alone now* (now that it is Christmas, now that these women think of "holy things").